# Nested virtual applications doesn't work?

Tags: azure

I'm having trouble setting up one Web Role with three sites (Azure v1.6, full trust).

Below is how it's configured in IIS Express:

```
<site name="Empty.Dummy.Site" id="2">
   <application path="/" applicationPool="appPool">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\Sites\Empty.Dummy.Site" />
   </application>
   <application path="/mainSite">
      virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Sites\mainSite" />
   </application>
  <application path="/mainSite/virtualChild">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\Sites\virtualChild" />
  </application>
   <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55555:localhost" />
   </bindings>
</site>

What's missing in ServiceDefinition.csdef is the "path" attribute.

I've tried a lot using nested virtual path and things but not got it to work.

For example:
<Sites>
   <Site name="Empty.Dummy.Site" physicalDirectory="c:\Sites\Empty.Dummy.Site >
      <VirtualApplication  name="mainSite" physicalDirectory="C:\Sites\mainSite">
          <VirtualApplication name="virtualChild" physicalDirectory="c:\Sites\virtualChild"/>
     </VirtualApplication>
      <Bindings><Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpIn"  /></Bindings>
</Site>
```

Any suggestions or other alternative?

The solution I am looking for should result in 3 sites within the same web role!

1. http://demo.cloudapp.net/
2. http://demo.cloudapp.net/MainSite/
3. http://demo.cloudapp.net/MainSite/VirtualChild

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to use for virtual applications that result in URLs like what you describe is (allegedly)

```
<Site name="Web">
   <VirtualApplication name="application-name" physicalDirectory="relative-location" />
   …
</Site>
```

I am not sure if it will support the http://demo.cloudapp.net/MainSite/VirtualChild scenario, though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx has a somewhat decent walk-through of the options.

Personally I prefer to use host-headers and get URLs like

1. http://demo.myapp.com/
2. http://main.myapp.com
3. http://virtualchild.myapp.com

If your setup is not static - i.e. you are planning to add sites dynamically - it is well worth having a look at the [Windows Azure Acceleratorfor Web Roles](http://blog.ntotten.com/2011/07/05/windows-azure-accelerator-for-web-roles/)

Comment: I have looked at Microsoft’s documentation and haven’t found an example of "my case". The thing that borders me is that is very easy to accomplish it in "IIS Express" or standard IIS but seems impossible in Azure...
In my scenario above I would like to have it as describes because is somewhat a composition of legacy application (web forms) and new MVC application and it has been mapped this way in IIS for a time so it’s unfortunately a bit of work to fix it.